# Live validation with jquery get method - only getting readyState 1

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I am attempting live validation when registering so users can see if their username has already been taken or not. Every time they type I am using jquery to send a get request to my controller which runs a query to check if their name is already taken. It sends back a "0" if it is not and a "1" if it is. When I run the get method I am only getting ready state 1. However I can see inside of that readyState the responseText its giving is correct. I have already tried accessing the responseText, to no prevail. I will attach a picture of the log.[Picture of log I am receiving back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj8eb.png)

```
   $(document).ready(() => {
    $("#usernameTaken").hide();
    function checkPassword() {
        let usernameGiven = $("#username").val();
        return $.get( "/getString", {username: usernameGiven})
            .done((data) => data)


    }

    $('#username').on('input', () => {
        console.log(checkPassword());

    });

});
```

My Controller

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    private Users userRepo;

    public TestController(Users userRepo) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping("/getString")
    public String getString(@RequestParam(name = "username") String username) {
        String count = String.valueOf(userRepo.checkForUsername(username));
        return JSONObject.quote(count);


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see in your console for network requests?

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to get you. What do you want to achieve and what issue are you facing? Are you expecting value from your response from web-service in `readyState` variable?

Comment: my controller returns a string that lets me know whether the name is taken already or not. I am wanting to pull out the responseText that you can see in the log that I linked to my og question. However, I am not able to do that.

Comment: You can see the correct response from your controller in ``responseText`` (in your attached picture of the log). It is the string ``"0"``. But jQuery.get is asynchronous, i.e. you receive the data in the ``.done(...)`` handler; but you are using the result of ``checkPassword`` in a synchronous way.

Comment: Thank you very much, I believe I fixed it by just adding a .then() after I call the checkPassword function on the change of input.

Comment: @matt that works, because [jQuery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR), so basically what jQuery calls a [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). So you are using the API asynchronously, but ``.then`` is always called, in case of failure or success. Check ``.done`` and ``.fail`` methods to distinguish between those. (jQuery deferred's API is a bit different from [JavaScript promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).)